# Access result of other field validation in a Zend Framework 2 validator

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a form with two dates, start and stop. I have a validator for start and I want to validate stop and also that stop is after start. But the after validation only makes sense if start is valid.

`isValid($value, $context = null)` could be passed the other values in the context variable, but then I have to do the start check again.

So is there a possibility to check the result of the start validation in the stop validator's `isValid()` function?

Comment: Use the `break_chain_on_failure` parameter in your validator spec -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841376/zf2-priority-for-validators-in-inputfilter/16841504#16841504 That way your stop validator will only be called if the start is valid to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Does this break the chain for one input or all inputs? Anyway, in both cases it is not exactly what I am looking for. Because stop is an additional input after start, and it must not be the last one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Callback](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#callback)

Or just write your [own validator](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.validator.writing-validators.html)

------ Edit - my proposed answer - Input filter with callback or validator ------

I do that like this.

First create a filter with all params:

```
namespace MyGreatNameSpace\Filter;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;

class MyDateFilter extends InputFilter
{

    public function __construct($myGreatClass)
    {

        $factory = new InputFactory();

        $this->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'       => 'start_date',
            'required'   => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Date',
                    'options' => array(
                        'format' => '2000-10-10',
                    ),
                )
            ),
        )));

        $this->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'       => 'end_date',
            'required'   => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Date',
                    'options' => array(
                        'format' => '2000-10-10',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name'              => 'Callback',
                    'options'           => array(
                        'callback'      => array($myGreatClass, 'isDateNewer'),
                        'messages'      => array(
                            'callbackValue'  => "The end date is Older then the start date",
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )));


    } // End of __construct
}
```

Create the [callback function](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#callback)

```
public function isDateNewer($date, $params)
{
    $date2 = $params['start_date'];

    if ($date > $date2) { // Over simplistic
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Implant in the controller (I used services to pull the form/filter class)

```
// Get the form / validator objects from the SM
$form   = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('date_form');
$filter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('date_filter');

// Inject the input filter object to the form object, load the form with data and bind the result to the model
$form->setInputFilter($filter);
$form->setData($post);
$form->bind($myModel); // (if you wish to bind the data to whatever)

if (!$form->isValid()) {
    return $this->forward()->dispatch.... (or whatever)
}
```

Another slightly diffrent way (though cleaner) is to write a validator. Check the [Zend\Validator\Identical](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#identical) (note the token)

```
array(
    'name' => '\Application\Validator\myNewNamedValidator',
    'options' => array(
        'token' => 'start_date',
        'messages' => array(
            'older' => "The end date is Older then the start date",
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of this possibilities but they do not solve the problem. The question is how to access results of former validations.

Comment: By former validation you mean a different scope that the stop is checked at? (different class, function, etc..)

Comment: One form with at least these two fields and each has its own validator. As I stated in the question I get in the `$context` variable the field values but not the validation result. At the moment I am redoing the validation of `start` in `stop`'s validator, as it makes no sense to validate that `stop` is after `start`, when `start` is not a valid date.

Comment: Assuming you get the start and stop from the same form and wish to check at the same location. Why dont you use inputFilter? If this is what you wish I can paste an example

Comment: Yes they are from the same form. Inside the inputFilter you specify a validator for each field. And inside these validators there is the problem for the stop validator.